# Electron app not launching

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

am working with angular version 6.1.0 and electron 2.0,on running the app in browser it but on  running npm run electron-build was successful but the app could not launch. thus, no browser window is displayed.

Here is the `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "front",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "electron": "electron .",
        "electron-build":"ng build --prod"
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is the `main.js` file:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

let win;
function createWindow (){
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 600,
        width:600,
        backgroundColor:'#ffffff'
    })
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`)
    win.on('closed',function(){
        win=null;
    })
}

app.on('ready',createWindow())

app.on('windows-all-closed',()=>{
    if(process.platform!=='darwin'){
        app.quit();
    }
})
app.on('activate',function(){
    if(win==null){
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you specify which platform you're running it on? One other thing is that you're requiring the `url` package but it doesn't seem to be in your package.json.

Comment: am running the app on win10 as for url, as you can am not actually using it, i should have remove or comment it out anyway

Comment: it works!, thanks @KirkLarkin you just helped me killed a 48hours-bug

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you're calling the `createWindow` function when the app first loads since in the ready event it thinks it should call the `createWindow` function straight away since it has the two brackets at the end.

To fix it just take the brakets off so it becomes:

```
app.on('ready',createWindow)
```

Thanks to @KirkLarkin for spotting the bug.